# Run a script located on remote server using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

I have a python script located on a remote server with SSH enabled. That script displays a lot of debug messages displayed while executing. I want to trigger this script using another python script which is on my local system and depending on the  output of the earlier script, I want to proceed further. While doing all this, I want the display messages on the remote server to be displayed on my local system as well. Basically, I want to view whatever output is thrown by the remote script during the course of the script, on my local system. I am able to trigger the script using paramiko but I am neither able to check whether the script on the remote server is running nor am I able to view it's output. Is there any way to do it? Already tried conn.recv(65535) but to no avail.

Comment: Why make this more complicated than it should be? Stat the terminal on the client, ssh into the server, stat the script and redirect both its stdout and stderr to a file. In the separate tab/window of your terminal follow the progress of the script using `tail -f /path/to/the/file`. You want to avoid shelling out from Python whenever possible. You can auto-schedule tasks with a cron job. You should have enough of the access to the server or else it is not very useful. What are your constraints?

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I found python fabric module easier than using paramiko. If you want to execute local script on remote machine using fabric. You just need to upload them using `put()` and then call `run()` api.

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put